# How to solve memory error in python when I have 32GRAM and py is 64bit

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am processing images using NumPy and Pillow and I have 32G of RAM, but all of the memory is being used. What can I do to improve my program? Here is my part code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *

img_rows,img_cols,img_depth=240,240,30
X_tr=[]

path = '/home/lt/Spyder/data1/brushing teeth/Depth1/'
imlist = os.listdir(path)
imlist.sort(key= lambda x:int(x[:-4]))
im = np.array(Image.open(path+imlist[0]))
m,n = im.shape[0:2]
imbr = len(imlist)
num = imbr-30 
i = 0

while i<num :
    frames=[]
    for k in range(30):
        im=np.array(Image.open(path+imlist[k+i]))
        frames.append(im)

    i=i+5
    input=np.array(frames)
    ipt = np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(input,2,0),2,0)
    X_tr.append(ipt) #265
```

The size of `X_tr` variable is 3751 rows, and my memory is on 99%. What should I do? Maybe I should process 100000 images, but that is only fourth of the data!

Comment: Is there a way to simplier this code? i delete some variables, but it's not working! and 300000 images is waiting process....

Comment: How big are these images you are trying to process?  If you can't fit everything in memory at once, you could try writing the results to a file as you go along.

Comment: the size is 200*200..Can you tell me more detail or where can I find same case about how to deal with it? thank you!

Comment: One technique I came across Youtube is to first process the image you want and save it somewhere in your hard drive. Then delete the processed image from the memory using `del image` before processing the next image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading all the files into memory as Image instances. Thus your images are too big to fit into memory. You should process less images or the images should be smaller in size.

However, you just seem to loop over it, thus if you use a generator you should be fine.

Your code is confusing in that you want to process everything but you only do every 5th frame? Anyway, here is some optimization:

```
# drop this, not needed
# i = 0 

# better memory data structure
# this should fix your memory problem
frames = collections.deque(maxlen=30)

# process every 5th frame?
# there seems to be a flaw in that you cut the last 30 but you
# when you start you also do not have 30. (can add if len(frames) < 30)
for file_name in files[::5]:
    frames.append(np.array(Image.open(path + file_name))
    input = np.array(frames)
    ipt = np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(input,2,0),2,0)
    X_tr.append(ipt) #265
```

Comment: Actually I'm not only do every 5th frame. I use 30 frames on the current frame as inputs to the 3D CNN model. The interval I set is 5. like 0-30 then 5-35, 10-40...of course it can be 0-30,1-31,2-32....